# getRecord method throws an error on console

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-development

Used to getRecord method ,throws error on console,any resolved solution?
This my code ,any i need to modify on code.

The error throws on console (image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2bDW.png)

```
     import { LightningElement, track, api,wire } from 'lwc';
        import { getRecord,getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
       
        @api recordId;
        @track LjobsValue;
        @track CjobsValue;
        @track MjobsValue;
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', layoutTypes: ['Full'], modes: ['View'] })
            
        
        wiredRecord({data,error}) {
            if (data) { 
            var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
           
            this.LjobsValue=getFieldValue(data,'Loan__c.Total_Jobs_Lost__c');
            this.MjobsValue=getFieldValue(data,'Loan__c.Total_Jobs_Maintained__c');
            this.CjobsValue=getFieldValue(data,'Loan__c.Total_Jobs_Created__c');
               }
               else{
                 this.error=error;  
                 console.log(error);
               }
           }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on what the expected outcome is? Perhaps things you've tried? Languages/context? It's a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This is lwc language in Salesforce ,the outcome is i need to get the fields values

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the space between `@wire` and the method to which you are wiring that is `wiredRecord()`? This may solve you error.